# Oracle: how to enable flashback "as of" queries for all developers?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I enable flashback queries for all of my developers on my Oracle instance?

Flashback queries are executed as of a particular time so that

```
select * from mytable as of timestamp(sysdate-1);
```

will show the contents of the table as of 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
grant execute on dbms_flashback to public;
grant flashback any table to public;
```

Comment: Mark, why did you mark 'Stephanie Page' answer as the correct answer? It is only a link and it does not have these commands in it. Your answer is the correct one.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez, you're right!  It must have been a mistake.  Fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use flashback query for your own tables without needing any privileges. If you want other users to use flashback query on your tables you need to grant select and flashback privileges to those users.

If you want to see data as of 24 hours ago you need to have an adequately sized undo tablespace and properly set undo retention.

[Also see this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_flashback.htm).

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_flashb.htm#BGBJEJGF

Comment: This link talks about enabling/disabling flashback for a particular session, not for the entire instance.